# How do I use a spreadsheet as a database behind a form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form where members of our sportsclub can register for tournaments.
Now every time members want to register they have to fill in all fields all over again (firstname, lastname, email address, category ...)
I have a spreadsheet (a google sheet) where I have all our members fix data. Can I create a field where I ask the members' registration number, and then based on that number do a lookup in the spreadsheet and fill in automatically all the fields in the form that I already know.
It seems straight-forward, when you have a db behind your code, but can I achieve this in forms linked to a spreadsheet ?

Comment: You cannot do this with Google Forms. You can create pre-filled forms, but they're not dynamic. If you created a simple HTML form served from a Google Sheet, you could, in theory, do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just ask them for the number and then insert rows on the spreadsheet from the form with their name etc. by matching their name by the number.

Comment: But can't you do that in the form with a lookup, so that 'at runtime' their name, etc appears on the form ? With scripting behind that field ?

Comment: You could change drop downs by using a dynamic drop down